# Set data-plugin-options programmatically in Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I have read this [docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown.html), and found plugin options that use inline on element itself. But it's look DRY code when I create several element with same plugin options.

For example I create a dropdown element with same plugin-options

```
<div class="dropdown-pane pop-menu" data-position="top" data-alignment="right" data-close-on-click="true" id="product-id1" data-dropdown></div>
<div class="dropdown-pane pop-menu" data-position="top" data-alignment="right" data-close-on-click="true" id="product-id2" data-dropdown></div>
```

How to set the data-plugin-options on Javascript? maybe somehing like this

```
Foundation.dropdown({
  position : 'top',
  alignment : 'right'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Foundation docs: [Configuring Plugins](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#configuring-plugins)

> Setting options with JavaScript involves passing an object into the
>   constructor function

In your case, it would be like:

```
var options = {position: 'top', alignment: 'right', closeOnClick: true};
var dropdown = new Foundation.Dropdown($('#product-id1, #product-id2'), options);
```